# Cssand js file not included in any file

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) this error to load css and js file.

Comment: Without seeing any code, my guess would be that it's failing to find your CSS and JS files.

Comment: what you mean i cant undestant  - im uploading .htaccess file in webroot,app folder

Comment: If you were to provide some relevant details from the .htaccess file, and info about what your directory structure looks like, and the code you're using to try to load them, then we can maybe give some suggestions or ask specific questions. With no such information, the problem could be anything. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on how to ask a good question.